# Mongo DB / Mongoose Conditional Inclusion Search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mongodb-query

I have a simple feature that may involve a complicated query. I want to allow users to only be shown to members they've already given approval to find them in my site.

The trouble is I have no idea how to add a conditional and then query within the queried users.

1. A user calls find.
2. If the searched users have "Approval Only" selected.
3. Check to see if the searching user is in their approved list.

I am using NodeJS with Mongoose for my finds.
Please help.

Schema below:

```
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userDOBs: {
    type: [Date],
    required: true
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  discoverySettings: {
    approvedOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  blockedProfileIDs: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "Profile"
  },
  approvedIDs: [
    {
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: "Profile"
    }
  ]
});
```

Query Below:

```
const profiles = await Profile.find({
        $and: [
          {
            _id: {
              $ne: req.user.profileID,
              $nin: doNotDisplayList
            },
            "loc.loc": {
              $nearSphere: [long, lat],
              $maxDistance: maxDistance
            },
            userDOBs: {
              $lt: moment().subtract(filter.searchParams.ageRange[0], "years"),
              $gt: moment().subtract(filter.searchParams.ageRange[1], "years")
            },
            active: true,
            "discoverySettings.visible": true,
            blockedProfiles: {
              $ne: req.user.profileID
            }
          }
        ]
      })
        .sort({
          updatedAt: -1
        })
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(skip);
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK Here's my schema: https://pastebin.com/CMTmqAvE

Comment: Here's my query:https://pastebin.com/AcuzPgNT

Comment: @JohnnyHK done and done. Thanks